# Is there a method for arudino to store values into different variables as soon as they come over a serial connection?

Tags: variables, arduino, serial-port

I have built an android app that will send a string of values (using getbyte()_) across a serial connection. I would like each of these values to be stored in a seperate variable/

For example:

a list of numbers like this:

```
10004056700003
```

are sent across the connection.

there are a bunch of variables on the arduino side:

A,B,C,D.... etc

i would like to be able to do this:

```
A = 1
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
E = 4
F= 0
```

.... and so on. i will then use these variables to run a certain sequence of functions on the arduino. In this sense the android application is just to control the arduino.

Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList of integer

Comment: You code is going to be on Arduino or on Android ? Remove from the tag the one that is not related. Anyway, this is not a good way to think, either on Java or on Arduino, you'd better use a List  or an Array

Comment: using the method i used to open a serial connection and send data - it only seemed to allow strings or bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

Serial communication usually happens byte-wise.

So if you want to transfer a sequence of numbers (>255) the easiest way is to send each digit as a byte.

On the receiving end you basically have two options.

a) you read each byte and do something with it befor reading the next byte.

b) you read the bytes into a buffer array and do something with it later.

If you want to minimize the number of bytes transferred you of course can split the number value into several bytes instead of transferring each digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the data as *String*, and then you can access each character of the String using the method: **StringVariableName.charAt(pos);**

With this approach, your code will be more readable.

Check out [charAt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/charat/) function here.